# Error occurred: ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted:

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a program where if I give it a web page and any word it will click that for example I can give it a Github profile and give the word "Follow" then it will press that follow button, and start following that Github profile.

How can I do this in Selenium? I'm currently getting this error: `Error occurred: ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted:`

Code:

```
import { Builder, By, until } from "selenium-webdriver";

async function clickElementWithText(url, targetText) {
  const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

  try {
    await driver.get(url);

    const element = await driver.wait(
      until.elementLocated(
        By.xpath(`//body//text()[contains(., '${targetText}')]/parent::*`)
      ),
      10000
    );

    await element.click();
    console.log(`Clicked on element containing "${targetText}"`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error occurred:", error);
  }
}

const url = "https://github.com/shs96c";
const targetText = "Follow";
clickElementWithText(url, targetText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Error is indicating that the element you're trying to click is overlapped by another element and therefore cannot be clicked.

To resolve this, you can try clicking the element using JavaScript instead of Selenium's click() method, for example:

```
import { Builder, By, until } from "selenium-webdriver";

const url = "https://github.com/shs96c";
const targetText = "Follow";

async function clickElementWithText(url, targetText) {
      const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

      try {
            await driver.get(url);
            const element = await driver.wait(
            until.elementLocated(
                  By.xpath(`//body//text()[contains(., '${targetText}')]/parent::*`)
                  ),10000);

            await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

            console.log(`Clicked on element containing "${targetText}"`);

      } catch (error) {

            console.error("Error occurred:", error);

      } finally {
            await driver.quit();
      }
}

clickElementWithText(url, targetText);
```

Edit:

Use fo JS the "querySelector" or "querySelector[x]" for selecting the element

Tell me if it works, if not, comment on this answer.

I hope it works 4 u

Comment: Hi! It works fine, Thank you very much. But will this work if Follow text or any other text is a button or <a> or any other HTML element?